# flink table api sink es on server has error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

2022-01-04 15:58:17
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings
at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkProcessor.builder(BulkProcessor.java:238)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.elasticsearch7.Elasticsearch7ApiCallBridge.createBulkProcessorBuilder(Elasticsearch7ApiCallBridge.java:80)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.elasticsearch7.Elasticsearch7ApiCallBridge.createBulkProcessorBuilder(Elasticsearch7ApiCallBridge.java:46)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkBase.buildBulkProcessor(ElasticsearchSinkBase.java:379)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkBase.open(ElasticsearchSinkBase.java:319)
at org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.util.FunctionUtils.openFunction(FunctionUtils.java:34)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.open(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:102)
at org.apache.flink.table.runtime.operators.sink.SinkOperator.open(SinkOperator.java:58)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain.initializeStateAndOpenOperators(OperatorChain.java:442)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreGates(StreamTask.java:585)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$1.call(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:55)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.executeRestore(StreamTask.java:565)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runWithCleanUpOnFail(StreamTask.java:650)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restore(StreamTask.java:540)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:759)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:566)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

1.1 I am aready put related jars into flink lib dir
1.2 I am set classloader.resolve-order  parent-first
1.3 flink version is 1.13.3
[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNdZH.png)

[add elasticsearch jars in flink lib dir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7Ntq.jpg)

[no errors when I  debug in intelli idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbKYc.png)

[classloader.resolve-order  parent-first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8agDw.png)

[with provided or without provided both has error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkepZ.png)
[with provided or without provided both has error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpjyI.png)
[the source at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkProcessor.builder(BulkProcessor.java:238)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ngTt.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

NoClassDefFoundError indicate that there may be a conflict in the es version, you can try to use the flink-sql-connector-elasticsearch jar package directly